# Replace list name with variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime

I have several dictionaries for each day of the week, Sunday `["a", "b", "c"]`, Monday `["d", "f", "g"]`, and so on, they are located in another script (xscript.py), and I would want to print them out depending on the day of the week I'm currently on, something like this:

```
import datetime
import xscript

def print_daily_list():
    day_of_week = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
    print(xscript.day_of_week)
```

I wouldn't want to create a bunch of `if` statements to replace `day_of_week` with "Sunday" or "Monday" depending on the day.

Comment: Using dictionary in fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses getattr to get the attribute of an object in this instance the module xscript. If the script module has a variable named Thursday and today is Thursday this script will get and print that variable.

```
day_of_week = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%A')
print(getattr(xscript, day_of_week))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can make a dictionary in xscript.py

```
dic = { 'Monday': ['a', 'b'], 'Sunday': ['e', 'f']}  # and all the weeks
```

and to access that I recommend creating a function in xscript, say

```
def get_dict(key):
    return dic.get(key, "Default List")
```

And now in your main file, you can call it like:

```
print(xscript.get_dict(day_of_week)
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed wrote, i have multiple dictionaries for each doy of the week not lists, I'm sorry, but Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a `dictionary`

```
days = {
    'Sunday': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Monday': [1, 2, 3],
    'Tuesday': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Wednesday': [1, 2, 3],
    'Thursday': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Friday': [1, 2, 3],
    'Saturday': [1, 2, 3],
}
```

Then pass the day of the week to your script, and call the dictonary with the day.

```
days[day]
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed wrote, i have multiple dictionaries for each doy of the week not lists, I'm sorry, but Thank you very much for your response

Comment: You can still use a dictionary. Just store what you need under each day.